# Why can't we use setAtrribute function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to use `setAttribute()` method in jquery as mentioned below :

```
$(p).setAttribute('class','first');
```

However that didn't work so I replaced `setAttribute` with `attr()` method.

```
$(p).attr('class','first');
```

It worked when I used the above code.

I just want to know why it didn't work when I used `setAttribute()` and why it worked when I used `attr()`?

Comment: `p.setAttribute('class','first');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) is a function in javascript works on DOM element where [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery function works on jQuery object (DOM Object)

you can check it by doing

```
$(p)[0].setAttribute('class','first');
```

OR

```
p.setAttribute('class','first'); // no need to wrap in $
```

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying my question :) @Dhaval Marthak

Comment: @Harish Glad it helped :)